# How to add text in the beginning and the end of the text matches with $

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

How to add text in the beginning and the end of the text matches with `$`

Input example:

```
$ hello
$  yes
r no change
```

I want to add the text to the beginning and the end of the file with a match `$`. I want output as

```
start $ hello end
start $  yes end 
r no change
```

Answer (score 4):

another `sed` approach:

```
sed '/^\$/ s/.*/start & end/' infile
```

in `sed`, `&` is the back-reference to the matched pattern part in `s/<pattern>/<replace>/`.

---

with `awk` you can also do the same:

```
awk '/^\$/{ $0="start " $0 " end" }1'  infile
```

in `awk`, `$0` represents the current record/line; records/lines separated based on awk's built-in `RS` (**R**ecord **S**eparator ) variable, which default is `\n`ewline; let's see some built-in variables default value they set when awk reads a record:

```
awk -d- '0' <<<'1'
```

awk consists of two parts `condition { action }` which at least one of these should exist in a awk command.

our condition here is a *pattern* and that is `/^\$/` (start `^` with a dollar `\$`, we escaped that because like `^` is anchor for the start of the record, `$` is the anchor for the end of that record).

in `$0="start " $0 " end"` we update the record by adding fixed strings `start`  and  `end` around it and write back to `$0`.

`/pattern/ { action }1`, the `1` is here actually is a always true condition that enables the aek's default print action; you can write any condition instead that results true and trigger the print action.

```
awk '/pattern/ { action }; 1!=0'
awk '/pattern/ { action }3'
...
```

or use the `print` action itself as well:

```
awk '/pattern/ { action }; { print }'
```

Comment: It worked for me, You are very fast. Thank you.

Comment: @GeetaPrasad you're welcome; please also read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed '/^\$/{s/^/start /; s/$/ end/;}' abc.txt
start $ hello end

start $  yes end

r no change
```